# Getting 'The current user cannot perform operations on cart' error while using Magento's GraphQL API via Remix.run. How to resolve?

Tags: magento2

I am currently building a storefront using Magento 2 and Magento's GraphQL API via Remix.run. However, when a customer tries to log in, they receive the error message: `The current user cannot perform operations on cart 'XXXXX'`. I am unsure what is causing this error and would appreciate any help or advice on how to resolve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you're receiving suggests that there may be an issue with the customer's shopping cart. Here are some steps you can take to troubleshoot the issue:

- Check the Magento logs: Magento logs may provide more details about
  the issue. Look for any error messages related to the shopping cart
  or customer login.
- Verify GraphQL API: Verify that the GraphQL API is set up correctly
  and that it's functioning properly. You can test the API using tools
  such as Postman or GraphQL Playground.

I hope these steps help you troubleshoot the issue and resolve it. Let me know if you have any further questions or concerns!

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I wanted to let you know that the API configuration has been successful. Currently, I am checking the Magento logs, and I will provide an update to you as soon as possible.